# Replace all the lines in a file with some new lines through ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have a file `/etc/init/test.list` in which I need to remove all the lines which is previously present and then insert below lines in it:

```
deb [arch=amd64] hello
deb [arch=amd64] world
```

I want to do this through ansible. Is  this possible to do? I was thinking to use `lineinfile` module but I am not sure how to do that here.

```
  - name: replace all lines
    lineinfile: 
      dest: /etc/init/test.list
```

Comment: So, replacing a file with entirely new contents?  You can use copy, or template commands.

Comment: yes with entirely new contents. Can you provide an example for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace a file with new contents, you can just [copy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html) a local (or from the remote system) file on top of it:

```
- name: example copying file with owner and permissions (from the sending machine)
  copy:
    src: /srv/myfiles/foo.conf
    dest: /etc/foo.conf
    owner: foo
    group: foo
    mode: 0644
    remote_src: no  # yes will look for the file on remote server

- name: Copy using the 'content' for inline data
  copy:
    content: '# This file was moved to /etc/other.conf'
    dest: /etc/mine.conf
```

If it was more complicated, you can use a [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html):

```
- name: Template a file to /etc/files.conf
  template:
    src: /mytemplates/foo.j2
    dest: /etc/file.conf
    owner: bin
    group: wheel
    mode: '0644'
```